# Working with Google Drive API on the google cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a google app engine site, and what I want to do, is get access to the files on my drive and publish them. Note that, my account owns both the drive and the app engine page.

I have tried looking at the google drive api, and the problem is that I don't know where to start with the following boilerplate code located in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server).

If you take a look at this function:

```
def get_credentials(authorization_code, state):
    """Retrieve credentials using the provided authorization code.

    This function exchanges the authorization code for an access token and queries
    the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's e-mail address.
    If a refresh token has been retrieved along with an access token, it is stored
    in the application database using the user's e-mail address as key.
    If no refresh token has been retrieved, the function checks in the application
    database for one and returns it if found or raises a NoRefreshTokenException
    with the authorization URL to redirect the user to.

    Args:
      authorization_code: Authorization code to use to retrieve an access token.
      state: State to set to the authorization URL in case of error.
    Returns:
      oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance containing an access and
      refresh token.
    Raises:
      CodeExchangeError: Could not exchange the authorization code.
      NoRefreshTokenException: No refresh token could be retrieved from the
                               available sources.
    """
    email_address = ''
    try:
        credentials = exchange_code(authorization_code)
        user_info = get_user_info(credentials)
        email_address = user_info.get('email')
        user_id = user_info.get('id')
        if credentials.refresh_token is not None:
            store_credentials(user_id, credentials)
            return credentials
        else:
            credentials = get_stored_credentials(user_id)
            if credentials and credentials.refresh_token is not None:
                return credentials
    except CodeExchangeException, error:
        logging.error('An error occurred during code exchange.')
        # Drive apps should try to retrieve the user and credentials for the current
        # session.
        # If none is available, redirect the user to the authorization URL.
        error.authorization_url = get_authorization_url(email_address, state)
        raise error
    except NoUserIdException:
        logging.error('No user ID could be retrieved.')
        # No refresh token has been retrieved.
    authorization_url = get_authorization_url(email_address, state)
    raise NoRefreshTokenException(authorization_url)
```

This is a part of the boilerplate code. However, where am I supposed to get `authorisation_code` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had to implement something similar, and it *is* quite tricky to find the relevant pieces of documentation.

This is what worked for me.

### One-time setup to enable Google Drive for your Google App Engine project

1. Go to the [Google APIs Console](http://developers.google.com/console) and select your App Engine project. If you don't see your App Engine project listed, you need to enable the cloud integration in the App Engine admin tool first (Administration > Application Settings > Cloud Integration > Create project)
2. In Google APIs Console, now go to Services and look for the "Drive API" in that long list. Turn it on.
3. Go to the API Access section on Google APIs Console, and find back the "Simple API Access" API Key. (see screenshot below)

[image: Simple API Access API key]

### Getting and installing the Python Drive API Client

4. Download the Python Drive API Client: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine
5. Documentation on this Python API: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/

### Using the Python Drive API Client

To create the Drive service object, I use this:

```
import httplib2

def createDriveService():
    """Builds and returns a Drive service object authorized with the
       application's service account.
       Returns:
           Drive service object.
    """
    from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

You can then use this service object to execute Google Drive API calls, for example, to create a folder:

```
service = createDriveService()
res = {'title': foldername, 
       'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"}
service.files().insert(body=res).execute()
```

### Caveats

I was not able to get the Drive API to work in unittesting, nor on the dev_appserver. I always get an error that my credentials are not valid. However, it works fine on the real app engine server.

Comment: May I just ask, how do you import `oauth2client` in google app engine?

Comment: It's included in the Python Drive API Client I linked to above. That package contains 4 folders: apiclient, httplib2, oauth2client and uritemplate. You'll need to upload all of these to AppEngine. Just include them in your project as you would any other python files.

Comment: I am afraid that this does not work anymore for app engine itself either. :( Can you show me how you'd import all your files as HTML documents, or atleast get a list of all your files on gdrive?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for app engine? Import what files as HTML documents? The code snippets I showed do still work on App Engine today, my app is actively using it...

Comment: Well, I tried to do the same thing that you just did, only with my API key, and as you said, it fails on localhost, but for me, it also fails when I actually host on appengine.

Comment: This is going to be hard to resolve by sending back and forth comments. I'm quite happy to do a chat session with you to help you troubleshoot, but I have no idea how to initiate this on StackOverflow. Do you?

Comment: I am sorry for this late reply. I am grateful that you would offer something like this. Perhaps, we can discuss in private? my email: gamesbrainiac@gmail.com